# IBM API Connect Test and Monitor giving Invalid Request error

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

I am trying to use API Connect Test and Monitor tool wherein when I gave a Get request and url and with and without authorization token, I am getting this error:

```
Error. Invalid Request
```

When I do it using Postman, I get a proper 200 OK response (with and without authorization token).

I have tried for POST request also. Same works in Postman but not in IBM API Test and Monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The IBM API Test and Monitor tool is a cloud-based service. Hence, it can only be used to query endpoints that are publicly available on the internet.

`localhost` refers to the user's computer which does not normally expose any TCP ports to the wider internet.

You can, however, use the [IBM API Test and Monitor desktop app](https://ibm-apiconnect.github.io/test-and-monitor/) to query `localhost`

Comment: Are its api's open source , because i want to capture its response. Or is there a way to capture its response in javascript like status code ?